# How to export apk from Android Studio with increased version number

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, version, google-play-console

I'm an artist who is trying to do his first game. I made it through all c# coding and created the app. After setting up Unity correctly to export an app for Google play, now I'm struggling to export a new version with increased number. I did increase it in the player settings and 'build an apk' but android studio doesn't read the increased number. I also exported a gradle project where this time the version number in the gradle file is correct, but I don't get the "build apk" button in the build options of Android Studio. Is there an easy way to increase it? Thank you and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0):

well in the end i discovered you can skip the android studio pass. You can sign the app in unity directly. I hade problem with the key thoug. To solve that, i created a new one and then re-exported with the old one. Don't ask why, but it worked.